# ContentControl inside a WPF TreeView

Tags: wpf

I am trying to add a content control inside a treeview, but when I add treeview items inside content control they are aligned further away from other treeview items.

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="XXX-1"></TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="XXX-2"></TreeViewItem>
    <ContentControl>
        <TreeViewItem Header="YYY-1"></TreeViewItem>
    </ContentControl>            
    <TreeViewItem Header="XXX-3"></TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

The above code results in a treeview like below.

```
XXX-1  
XXX-2  
  YYY-1  
XXX-3
```

I think ContentControl adds another TreeViewItem by itself. How can I align the TreeViewItems together?

Comment: What is the goal of adding the TreeViewItem to a ContentControl?

Comment: @Josh : Please see the comment I wrote to Orchestrator.

Comment: put an answer below that should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with Rachel's answer but remove the ContentControl.  You can accomplish this with two DataTemplates and an ItemTemplateSelector assigned to the TreeViewItem's ItemTemplateSelector property.

Define your complex and simple types into two DataTemplates.  Then write a class which inherits from DataTemplateSelector that determines if the complex or simple type should be used in the TreeViewItem.  You then set the TreeViewItem's ItemTemplateSelector to the DataTemplateSelector object you just created.  Here's is an example:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx.

Here is another link that shows you how to select a DataTemplate based on a condition:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx.  Search for the header **Choosing a DataTemplate Based on Properties of the Data Object**.

Answer (score 0):

It does nest the ContentControl in a TreeViewItem (see [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) screenshot below)

Snoop also tells me that the extra margin is for the +/- Expander, so you'll probably have to overwrite the template to get rid of that margin if you want to keep your TreeViewItems nested.

[image]

Of course, if you're simply trying to place a ContentControl inside your TreeViewItem, the tags should be the other way around.

```
<TreeViewItem Header="YYY-1">
    <ContentControl />
</TreeViewItem>
```

Comment: What do you mean by overwriting the template? Is it possible to change the rendering of ContentTemplate inside a TreeView so that it only acts as a placeholder? Btw I didn't know about the Snoop, it's a very handy tool thanks.

Comment: @user1106026 By default, WPF controls are "lookless", meaning the way they appear on the screen is not defined in the Control itself. Instead, WPF uses Templates to determine how to draw UI objects on the screen, and these Templates can be overwritten. For example, the Snoop screenshot shows that the `TreeViewItem` is being drawn as a `Grid` containing an `Expander` and a `Border`, and the `Border` contains the `ContentPresenter`. You could overwrite this so it only draws the `ContentPresenter`